# Statistical method to combine/summarize multiple R squared values

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, r-squared

I have a set of measurements using two different methods.  I Have 6 samples that I have measurements for using both methods.   I am trying to demonstrate how comparable the measurements are from the two methods.

One way of showing this relationship that is by plotting the measured data from the two methods in a scatter plot where the Y-axis is the measurement from one method, and the X-axis is the measurement from the other, and calculating an R-squared statistic to show how linearly correlated the methods are.

I was wondering if there was a statistic that summarizes/combines/averages multiple R-squared statistics.  IN my case I Have 6 samples for which I can calculate an R-squared stat, but I haven't found a good way of summarizing that info, or a different method to calculate a "combined R-squared" statistic.

Please let me know if my request is unclear and I will try to elaborate.
Thanks!